# Push notifications to specific users or devices

Tags: javascript, push-notification, notifications, signalr, sqldependency

I have a WEB MVC 5 system in which I use signalR and SqlDependency to be in real time, but this is not the case what I need to implement are push notifications to system administrators when there are changes of interest. Being specific what I need is a mechanism to send push notifications to specific users and if possible, even if they are not connected, that is, even if they are not using the system.

I searched a lot, I was using the push.js library but this does not allow me to do this or I think so.

Any mechanism that can provide that covers my needs or something similar will be received.

Comment: I implemented a similar program that you need help for, 1 year ago. I am sending notifications to the connected users. I can send my codes to you but first, I need to rearrange it according to your needs.

Comment: Thank you, but are you able to choose which users to notify?

Comment: I am able to select which user to push notifications, Are you able to provide the code you wrote for this.

Comment: Do you have any method to help me with my question?

Comment: Did you check out my answer?

Comment: Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a Stored Procedure(SP) which returns the event details according to user. You can create a table that keeps the ID of you want to send the notification, and every insert to this table will notify the user.

I have three tables as 'User','Events','UserEvents'.
In UserEvents Table there is userID as foreign key from user table and eventID as foreign key from events table. In my system, when the event inserted to the tables above, signalR do its job.
UserEvents Table has the columns like below:

```
   [Uev_ID]
  ,[Uev_UserID]
  ,[Uev_EventID]
  ,[Uev_IsRead]
  ,[Uev_ReadDate]
  ,[GuID]
  ,[Deleted]
```

My Event Model is like below:

```
    public class EventList
    {
    public Int64 EventID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    }
```

There should be a Message Repository to interact and communicate with database and model. This repository will handle the dependency_OnChange method.

```
    public class MessagesRepository
    {
    internal static SqlCommand command = null;
    internal static SqlCommand command2 = null;
    internal static SqlDependency dependency = null;
    internal static SqlDependency dependency2 = null;
    readonly string _connString = 
                  ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["signalr"].ConnectionString;
    private Int64 user { get; set; }
    public MessagesRepository(Int64 userID)
    {
        user = userID;
    }

    public IEnumerable<EventList> GetAllMessages()
    {
        var messages = new List<EventList>();
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (command = new SqlCommand("[sp_SysEvent]", connection))
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", user);
                command.Notification = null;

                if (dependency == null)
                {
                    dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                    dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);
                }
                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    connection.Open();

                var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    messages.Add(item: new EventList { EventID = (Int64)reader["Evt_ID"], Description = (string)reader["Evt_Description"], Title = (string)reader["Evg_Title"], Date = (DateTime)reader["Evt_Date"], Color = (string)reader["Clr_Color"] });
                }
            }
        }
        return messages;
    }

    private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dependency != null)
        {
            dependency.OnChange -= dependency_OnChange;
            dependency = null;
        }
        if (e.Info == SqlNotificationInfo.Insert)
        {

            TestHub.SendUser(user);
        }
    }
}
```

I needed a Connection Mapping document for sending the notifications to the connected users. When a user connected, I put its ID to a HashSet and Remove from HashSet when a user disconnected. You can use this to detect which user is connected.
Here is the connection mapping:
        public class ConnectionMapping
        {
        private Dictionary> _connections = new Dictionary>();

```
    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return _connections.Count;
        }
    }


    public void Add(T key, string connectionId)
    {
        lock (_connections)
        {
            HashSet<string> connections;
            if (!_connections.TryGetValue(key, out connections))
            {
                connections = new HashSet<string>();
                _connections.Add(key, connections);
            }

            lock (connections)
            {
                connections.Add(connectionId);
            }
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> GetConnections(T key)
    {
        HashSet<string> connections;
        if (_connections.TryGetValue(key, out connections))
        {
            return connections;
        }

        return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
    }
    //public IEnumerable<string> GetConnections2(T key)
    //{
    //    List<HashSet<string>> connections;
    //    if (_connections.Any(x => x.Key.ToString().Contains(key.ToString())))
    //    {
    //        connections = _connections.Where(x => x.Key.ToString().StartsWith(key.ToString() + "_")).Select(x => x.Value);
    //    }

    //    return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
    //}
    public void Remove(T key, string connectionId)
    {
        lock (_connections)
        {
            HashSet<string> connections;
            if (!_connections.TryGetValue(key, out connections))
            {
                return;
            }

            lock (connections)
            {
                connections.Remove(connectionId);

                if (connections.Count == 0)
                {
                    _connections.Remove(key);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the Hub document is:

```
public class TestHub : Hub
{
    private readonly static ConnectionMapping<string> _connections = new ConnectionMapping<string>();
    public string GetUserGroup()
    {
        string abc = "";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["signalr"].ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            string sqltheme = "Select Usr_GroupID from SysUser where ID=" + Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.Split('_')[1]) + "";
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqltheme, connection))
            {
                abc = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            }
        }
        return abc;
    }
    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        string name = "";
        try
        {
            name = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.Split('_')[1];
            Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, GetUserGroup());
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            name = Context.ConnectionId;
        }
        if (_connections.GetConnections(name).Count() > 0)
        {
            _connections.Remove(name, _connections.GetConnections(name).ToString());
        }
        _connections.Add(name, Context.ConnectionId);
        return base.OnConnected();
    }
    [HubMethodName("send")]
    public void Send(string mes)
    {
        Clients.All.send(mes); // if you want to send all user use this.
    }
    [HubMethodName("sendUser")]
    public void SendUser(string[] who, int id, string title)
    {
        string name = Context.User.Identity.Name;
        foreach (var user in who)
        {
            foreach (var connectionId in _connections.GetConnections(user))
            {
                Clients.Client(connectionId).sendUser(id, title);
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

Lastly, the javascript code to call the hub functions:

```
var myhub = $.connection.testHub;
        $(function () {
            $.connection.hub.start();
            chat.client.sendUser = function (id, title) {
                var count = parseFloat($("#header_notification_bar > a > span").text()) + 1;
                $("#header_notification_bar > a > span").text(count);
                toastr.info('Bir Yeni Bildiriminiz Var.Görüntülemek İçin Tıklayınız.', 'Bildirim', {
                    closeButton: true, timeOut: 20000, onclick: function () {
                        window.location.href = '/tr/Notification/List';
                    }
                });
                $("#notification_list").prepend("<li><a href='javascript:;' style='background-color:#e6e6e6' class='okunmadi' id='" + id + "'><span class='time' style='min-width:100px;'>şimdi</span><span class='details'><span class='label label-sm label-icon label-success'><i class='fa fa-bullhorn'></i></span>" + title + "</span></a></li>");
            };
```

I wish it works for you, too.